# Create tag retrospectively?

Tags: discussion, tags

I searched for the [[rinruby] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rinruby), but it yielded no results.

So I searched for it as free text: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rinruby

I think it would be useful if those questions had the [rinruby] tag, but it doesn't exist. Is it wise to create such a tag for these questions that already exist under other tags?

Comment: You have full editing privileges. If you think the tag is beneficial as a way to categorize questions, then you can create it by just editing a question and adding the tag to it. However, please don't just go mass-editing a bunch of questions to add tags. That can be very disruptive to other users' view of the site (specifically, the front page, which shows recently active questions). Space out your edits a bit, spreading them out over days or weeks if possible. Also, while editing the question to add a tag, make sure that you fix other glaring problems.